# Determining values in a bitmask

Tags: c#

I have a protocol guide for a piece of hardware where I can extract 16 different kinds of data. To indicate I want all data, I would enter 65535 as the mask.

```
  2^0  (1)
+ 2^1  (2)
+ 2^2  (4)    
...    
+ 2^15  (32768)
==============
65535
```

I now need to indicate I need options 9, 10, and 13. Presumably I simply need to use the following calculation:

```
  2^9   (512)
+ 2^10  (1024)
+ 2^13  (8192)
==============
9728
```

(If I'm off-base here, or there is a programmatic way to do this, I'd be interested to know!)

What I would like to know is how I would in future extract all the numbers that were involved in the summation.

I had thought I would be able to check with `(9728 & 9) == 9`, `(9728 & 10) == 10`, and `(9728 & 13) == 13`, but all those return false.

Comment: You need to do the bitwise and with 2^9 instead of 9 and compare it to 2^9.

Comment: Try using `<<`, e.g. `2**9 == 1 << 9, 2**13 == 1 << 13`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

bit 9 is 256; bit 10 is 512; bit 13 is 4096.

So:

```
if((val & 256) != 0) { /* bit 9 is set */ }
if((val & 512) != 0) { /* bit 10 is set */ }
if((val & 4096) != 0) { /* bit 13 is set */ }
```

You could also use an enum for convenience:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyFlags {
     None = 0,
     Foo = 1,
     Bar = 2,
     ...
     SomeFlag = 256,
     AnotherFlag = 512,
     ...
}
```

then:

```
MyFlags flags = (MyFlags)val;
if((flags & MyFlags.SomeFlag) != 0) {/* SomeFlag is set */}
```

And likewise:

```
MyFlags thingsWeWant = MyFlags.Foo | MyFlags.SomeFlag | MyFlags.AnotherFlag;
int val = (int)thingsWeWant;
```

Comment: If you use a Flags enum, you can use the `HasFlag` method instead of manually "and-ing"

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus that is actually not a good idea; `HasFlag` takes `Enum` - so it involves *boxing*.

Answer (score 2):

Did mean sth like this?

```
var value = 512 | 1024 | 8192;

var pos = 9;
var isSetNine = (value & (1 << pos)) != 0;
```

Comment: What does the `pos` variable signify?

Comment: @MisterEpic the position on bit (the power of two) that you want to check. It may be 9, 10 or 13 like in your sample.